# IntelliJ recognizes class but "can't access class"

Tags: intellij-idea

I've used IntelliJ a good bit and never seen this happen. Here's a screenshot I've what I'm seeing. I just started this project, I've tried deleting the problem Vehicle class and putting it back, still has an error. I've tried File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart. Nothing. I've updated to the latest version. Not really sure what to do about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[Class attempting to create a Vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2wMN.png)

[Vehicle class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D61Xr.png)

Comment: what's up in the `Vechicle` class? and show the whole class, also the imports and package stuff

Comment: @Edwin added the Vehicle class. Let me know if you need to see anything else

Comment: have a look over: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html